ESXi 6.7 PSOD: NOT_IMPLEMENTED bora/vmkernel/hardware/pci/pci.c:412
I’m encountering a Purple Screen of Death (PSOD) on my ESXi 6.7 host during boot. The error message displayed is:
NOT_IMPLEMENTED bora/vmkernel/hardware/pci/pci.c:412

My Setup:
ESXi Version: 6.7.0 (Release Build: 14320388)
CPU: Intel Core i5 12th Gen (no integrated GPU)
Graphics Card: some graphic card
Network Adapter: Intel 82576 GE 2T x1

This is happening on a new installation of ESXi 6.7.
Since my CPU doesn’t have an integrated GPU, I am using a discrete graphics card for display.
I suspect the issue might be related to the network adapter, graphics card, or compatibility with the 12th Gen CPU.
Questions:
Does the pci.c:412 error indicate incompatibility with my graphics card, network adapter, or CPU?
Are there any known compatibility issues with 12th Gen Intel CPUs, the Intel 82576 NIC, or specific GPUs on ESXi 6.7?

